# How to disable certain component from Bootstrap on Laravel

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel, sass, gulp, glyphicons

One would imagine I'm not the only one trying to achieve this, so I was surprised that I couldn't find an answer in Google. I'm googling with wrong keywords perhaps..

I'm looking for a way to disable the Glyphicons component from Bootstrap on my Laravel application. I'm using the SASS version of Bootstrap.

Only way I can imagine is to comment out this line `@import "bootstrap/glyphicons";` inside `node_modules/bootsrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap.scss` but if I understood correct, that would be an bad idea since the content of that directory will be overwritten by updates on the bootstrap module. Am I right?

How else could I prevent the SASS processor from importing the Glyphicons?

Would it be a lasting solution to take a copy of the `_bootstrap.scss` file to my `resources/assets/sass/`, and there comment out the Glyphicon-line and then reference that file from my `app.scss` ?

As this is a long-term project, I want to be careful with the architecture...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up solving this the way I suggested in the post:

1. Copy `_bootstrap.scss` from `node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheet` to `resources/assets/sass/`
2. `@import` the copied file to `app.scss` instead of the one in the `node_modules` directory.
3. Comment out the components that are not needed, such as Glyphicons.

I'm still interested to hear of potential downsides this solution might have, but as far as I can see, this shouldn't require extra maintenance or duplicate work in the future.

P.S. If anyone knows a way to add `node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/` to the Sass load path in Laravel environment, it would be helpful. 
For some reason I didn't get this working: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/setting-include-path-for-sass-in-elixir